React web app PKCE Authentication against Authority Server
I'm currently working on implementing authentication for a basic React template with an Authority server. While I'm a bit rusty on React, I believe I've successfully integrated all the necessary components into my client application.
When I launch the application, the login page appears. After entering my credentials and clicking the Login button, I'm redirected to the home page. However, it begins refreshing endlessly, and the only thing I notice is that the code in the URL parameters keeps changing.
Firstly, I've implemented a wrapper for my App component to manage authentication:
// index.js
...
<AuthWrapper>
  <App />
</AuthWrapper>
...

Here's the definition of AuthWrapper:
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AuthProvider } from './AuthContext';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const AuthWrapper = ({ children }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  return (
    <AuthProvider navigate={navigate}>
      {children}
    </AuthProvider>
  );
};

export default AuthWrapper;

I've also defined AuthProvider (currently, I've hard-coded the code verifier; I need to figure out how to move it to the app's context):
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";
import {generateCodeChallenge} from "utils/authutils";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
const AuthContext = createContext();
export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);
export const AuthProvider = ({ children, navigate }) => {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  const codeChallenge = generateCodeChallenge('dce35c1f-194d-48c4-bd90-6f14e9042023');

  const login = () => {
    window.location.href = "https://localhost/Identity/authorize" +
      "?client_id=web_client" +
      "&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/authentication/callback" +
      "&response_type=code" +
      "&scope=web_scope offline_access" +
      "&state=123" +
      `&code_challenge=${codeChallenge}` +
      "&code_challenge_method=S256";
  };

  const handleLoginCallback = () => {
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const code = urlParams.get("code");
    setIsAuthenticated(true);
    navigate("/dashboard");
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ isAuthenticated, login, handleLoginCallback }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

Secondly, I've created a callback page, which is the one I've configured in the Authority server:
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { exchangeAuthorizationCode } from "services/api";

const CallbackPage = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
    const authorizationCode = searchParams.get("code");

    if (authorizationCode) {
      exchangeAuthorizationCode(authorizationCode).then((accessToken) => {
        localStorage.setItem("accessToken", accessToken);
        navigate("/dashboard");
      });
    } else {
      navigate("/error");
    }
  }, [location.search, navigate]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Redirecting...</p>
    </div>
  );
};
export default CallbackPage;

Here's the definition of api.js (note the code_verifier is the same):
export const exchangeAuthorizationCode = async (authorizationCode, codeVerifier) => {
    const requestBody = {
      grant_type: "authorization_code",
      code: authorizationCode,
      redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000/authentication/callback",
      code_verifier: 'dce35c1f-194d-48c4-bd90-6f14e9042023', 
      client_id: "web_client"
    };
  
    try {
      const response = await fetch("https://localhost/Identity/token", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
      });
  
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Failed to exchange authorization code for access token");
      }
  
      const data = await response.json();
      return data.access_token;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error exchanging authorization code:", error.message);
      throw error;
    }
  };

Finally, in my App page, I've included a segment for redirection:
...

import { useAuth } from "AuthContext";

export default function App() {

  ...
  
  const { isAuthenticated, login } = useAuth();
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isAuthenticated && pathname !== "/login") {
      login(); // method to redirect to the authority server
    }
  }, [isAuthenticated, pathname, login]);

  ...

  const getRoutes = (allRoutes) =>
    allRoutes.map((route) => {
      if (route.collapse) {
        return getRoutes(route.collapse);
      }

      if (route.route) {
        return <Route exact path={route.route} element={route.component} key={route.key} />;
      }

      return null;
    });

    ...

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={darkMode ? themeDark : theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Routes>
        {getRoutes(routes)}
        <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/dashboard" />} />
      </Routes>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

The complete code can be found here

I had a few issues, but the one that did the trick was this piece:
useEffect(() => {
    // Redirect to login page if not authenticated
    if (!isAuthenticated && pathname != "/authentication/callback") {
      login();
    }
  
  }, [isAuthenticated, login, pathname]);

Previously, I was validating against the "login" page, but this page doesn't exist in the React app; it is part of the authority server. So, all I needed to do was replace the path with the callback page.
